# Delete contents of file in PHP during stream

Tags: php, stream, firebase, guzzle

I'm running a REST stream from Firebase with Laravel.

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

$url = FirebaseUrlWithAuthKey;

$headers = ['headers'=>['Accept' => 'text/event-stream'],'stream'=>true];

$response = $guzzle->request('GET', $url,$headers);

$body = $response->getBody();

while (!$body->eof()) 
{
    $this->doSomethingWithData($body->read(8192));

}
```

Listening to a Firebase node requires us to download all the existing data before listening for changes.

This is problematic as we have a lot of data at the node we're listening to and it's taking ***EIGHT*** minutes to download the initial data set because the `fread()` PHP function seems to only be able to chunk 8192B.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to truncate the initial dataset before listening to the node?
2. Can I chunk more than 8192B with the `fread()` function?

Thanks!

Comment: your example code doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. Where would any of this reading/deleting take place?

Comment: Reference PHP Stream chunk size: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-chunk-size.php